# ng-model does not work in select directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-model

**What is working:** The `ng-options` contains all names and it is shown in the dropdown-list.

**Problem:**

1. At the beginning if nothing is selected, there should the text "Select name..." displayed. But it's empty right now.
2. I know it has been asked a lot but I didn't found a solution with this case.
   If I will select some of those options the Error

> "Error: [$compile:nonassign] Expression 'undefined' used with
>   directive 'fileWidget' is non-assignable!" occured.

GeometryService.js

```
angular.module('COMLEAMclient')
.factory('GeometryService', function($resource) {

  var selectedGeometry = {name:'Select name...'};
}
```

FileWidgetDirective.js

```
angular.module('COMLEAMclient')
.directive('fileWidget', ['$log', '$parse', function($log, $parse) {

        return {
            scope: {
                data: '=',
                selectedFile: '=',
                updateSelection: '&',
                selected: '=',
                onReadFile: '&',
            },
           ....
        }
    )
}
```

InputController.js

```
<div file-widget data="iCtrl.geometryFiles"  update-selection= "iCtrl.setSelectedGeometry(name)" selectedFile= "iCtrl.selectedGeometryFile" on-read-file="iCtrl.saveGeometryFiles(file,name)"></div>
```

FileWidget.html

```
<select class="form-control"
    ng-options="elem.name for elem in data"
    ng-model="selectedFile"
    ng-change="onSelectionChange()">
</select>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have `Select name...` you need to have an `option` element:

```
<select class="form-control"
    ng-options="elem.name for elem in data"
    ng-model="selectedFile"
    ng-change="onSelectionChange()">
    <option value="">Select name...</option>
</select>
```

You are trying to assign to an object, and that is non assignable, which is why you're getting the `non-assignable` error. You need to have a variable that can contain the value the selected option, try:

```
ng-model="selectedFile.name"
```

Comment: I canged my code to

   <select class="form-control"
       ng-options="elem.name for elem in data"
       ng-model="selectedFile.name"
       ng-change="onSelectionChange()">
       <option value="">Select name...</option>
   </select>

but got still the same excepion. probably there is more than just this.

Comment: @MarcelTinner Perhaps `selectedFile.name` is also non-assignable. Can you share that obj?

Comment: it sould be this on in the GeometryService.js -->  var selectedGeometry = {name:'Select name...'};

Comment: I don't recommend binding straight from the view to the service's variable. Place it on the controller somewhere. Also now it looks like your variable is private to the GeometryService.